# How to do SSH from PHP?

Tags: php, linux

I have a database of [server, username, password] records and I need to programatically connect to those machines via SSH, execute a remote **sudo** command (install some applications using `apt-get` or whatever is available on the server) and retrieve the output (exitcode would be nice, but output is enough). How can I do this from PHP?

Comment: I would have first looked at socket programming in PHP.

Comment: Read the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php And start with `ssh2_connect()`

Comment: @Michael, thanks, reminds me to do RTFM before I ask a question here

Comment: Before to (maybe) reinvent the wheel , try to take a look into the puppet project: http://www.puppetlabs.com/

Comment: @Francesco: Funny you should mention that, I want to execute a few remote commands to install ruby and Puppet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo is a bit tricky but [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), makes it a ton easier:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$sftp = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$sftp->login('username', 'password');

echo $sftp->read('username@username:~$');
$sftp->write("sudo ls -la\n");
$output = $sftp->read('#Password:|username@username:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#Password:#', $lines)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $sftp->read('username@username:~$');
}
?>
```

I just copy / pasted that from the phpseclib docs actually:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_sudo

Answer (score 1):

[PHP has a native SSH client](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) (a good [tutorial](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/make_ssh_connections_with_php/) was originally mentioned by another poster) but it requires that you have the authority to install and run libssh2 under Linux. I've never gotten it to work under Windows, but I haven't really tried in a couple of years, so it might be easier than it was.

When I last needed to do something like that I used [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html). It is a good, reliable package which has SSH and SFTP support (it is also PHP4 compatible).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the php function [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Try setting up a bash script to SSH using public/private keys and do what you need it to do, then just execute the script with `exec()` in PHP.